# Fresh new session for rstudio-server

Tags: r, rstudio-server, vmware-player

I am running rstudio-server on a virtualised (vmware-player) ubuntu machine, and processing lots of data into the ram. I find that after some inactivity that the session suspends the data. The problem is that it takes a VERY long time to resume this session and it is making both the host machine and virtual machine lag very badly.

I just want to kill the session and start a new fresh session of rstudio-server, but so far the only way I have found which does this is to `reisub` my ubuntu machine. Does anyone know a better solution?

As a side note, I think entering `session-timeout-minutes=0` in `/etc/rstudio/rsession.conf` as per [here](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/server/configuration) should fix the problem of the session suspending.

Comment: Does http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/server/management help you?

Comment: nope :( there is no command to terminate the session. I have also tried all the commands which I think might help from that page, to no avail.

Comment: I can't answer my own question, but here is this answer:

I finally found [this page], which deals with resetting the rstudio-desktop version. In my home directory, I found the folder `~/.rstudio`. I renamed/deleted this folder and this loads a new rstudio-server instance.

[this page]: http://support.rstudio.org/help/kb/troubleshooting/resetting-rstudios-state

Comment: As far as I know you can answer your own question.  I have.  I suggest you post an answer with the details of your solution.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I can now, there is a 8 hour limit for new users to answer their own questions.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I found [this page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218730228-Resetting-a-user-s-state-on-RStudio-Server), which deals with resetting the rstudio-desktop version. In my home directory, I found the folder `~/.rstudio`. I renamed/deleted this folder and this loads a new rstudio-server instance.

In fact, there is a folder called `suspended session` in the `~/.rstudio` folder, which I suspect is the thing where suspended data is stored, so maybe deleting this folder is sufficient?

Comment: Deleting a folder called suspended session is enough. Thanks

Comment: The suspended session was the problem on my case.

Comment: the link is dead!

Comment: @MLavoie Thanks, I have updated it with what I think is the new link.

Answer (score 8):

If there is a directory inside `~/.rstudio/sessions/active/`, deleting it (in the way like `rm -rf ~/.rstudio/sessions/active/session-*`) might be sufficient to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Note that with newer versions of Rstudio, this folder is now under

> ~/.local/share/rstudio/sessions/

while in some older versions, it can also be seen in `~/.rstudio-desktop`, see [documentation page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a while back but after running into this problem a zilion times i found a way to reset the Rstudio Shiny Server session without the need for admin rights on Rstudio Shiny Server:

- put temporarily as first line in server.r :
      quit("yes") # FORCE CLOSE OF SESSION server
- go to the site and it will crash (the session closes straight away)
- delete or comment out:
  # quit("yes") # FORCE CLOSE OF SESSION server
- go to the site and you will have the shiny app with a new session =^)

Works for me and saves a lot of time searching through all kind of system folders or the need to enter a part of the system that you are not allowed to go or needing admin rights on Rstudio Shiny Server.

I hope this helps.

Comment: while this looks to be a very useful hack for users running `Shiny` on `shiny-server`, my question is actually about rstudio server edition, not shiny server :)

Comment: Sorry, i mean running a Shiny app with R studio Server. To get a new session in R studio / R studio server you can just select Restart R in the Session menu (if this is what you mean)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the above solutions which didn't work for me. I tried to kill the rsession which is causing the problem. just run this command to find out pid of user session. 

ps -u userid

Find out the pid that is causing the rsession to stall. Kill that process and you're good to go.

Comment: For me, `rsession` was not listed in `ps`, I had to use `top` to find it and then get the process ID and `kill` it.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to rename ~/.rstudio and reopen the webpage using rstudio url.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the updates on Rstudio and [as it was announced on August 30, 2023](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/218730228-Resetting-a-user-s-state-on-Posit-RStudio-Workbench-RStudio-Server), the files are ttored in two places:

- `~/.config/rstudio/`: All user settings (Global Options)
- `~/.local/share/rstudio/`: All open files and tabs, as well as active and suspended sessions.

Therefore, you can flush/clear/delete the files of the session by:

1. kill the active session (or kill all sessions)

   ```bash
   # get the PID
   rstudio-server active-sessions

   # kill the specific session
   sudo rstudio-server kill-session 25039  # or whatever the your PID is
   ```

   or

   ```bash
   sudo rstudio-server kill-all
   ```
2. Renaming the session files:

   ```bash
   mv "${HOME}/.local/share/rstudio" "${HOME}/.local/share/rstudio-old"
   ```
3. Restarting Rstudio

   ```bash
   sudo rstudio-server restart
   ```

Now open the Rtsudio in the browser and check if everything works normally. you can then delete the session you marked as `old` by the following:

```bash
rm -rf "${HOME}/.local/share/rstudio-old"
```