# RStudio server - Hangs when switching projects

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I am currently running RStudio via a server installation that I only partially maintain. I am working with some fairly large data sets and models (> 9 million rows of 611 variables).  When I try to switch projects, RStudio hangs when loading the project (it says "Switching projects to..." at the top) or, if it loads, takes forever.

RStudio works otherwise while attempting to switch projects, but menus and the like do not work.

I have searched thoroughly for a fix to no avail.  How would I go about troubleshooting (or, ideally, fixing) the problem?

RStudio is running on a linux (Open SuSE) VM.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Per this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15373596/3469671, I deleted .rstudio from my home directory and that seemed to free things up. Is there some setting I can change to facilitate the loading of larger projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15373596/3469671), I deleted .rstudio from my home directory and that seemed to free things up.

As a practice, I learned to stop saving my workspace while it was loaded with data and included steps within projects to save and load prepared data.